# error handling causing "Cast from 'Custom_Class?' to unrelated type 'UIViewController' always fails" error

Tags: swift

Conversion to Swift 2.3. I've had to find a new solution for my error handling and decided to use try! here. I don't think this is the most elegant or efficient way to do this and the warning supports this.

> Cast from 'SuperID?' to unrelated type 'UIViewController' always fails

ViewController.swift

```
    @IBAction func longPressAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    getAuthorityOfCamera()

    let error : NSError? = nil;

    // error 
    let SIDEmotionViewController  = try! superIdSdk?.obtainFaceFeatureViewController() as? UIViewController

    if SIDEmotionViewController != nil{
        self.presentViewController(SIDEmotionViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        print("\(error?.code)     \(error?.description)")
    }
}
```

SuperID.h

```
@interface SuperID : NSObject

@property(assign,nonatomic) id<SuperIDDelegate> delegate;

+ (SuperID *)sharedInstance;

// snip

- (instancetype)obtainFaceFeatureViewControllerWithError:(NSError **)error;

- (instancetype)obtainAdvancedFaceFeatureViewControllerWithError:(NSError **)error;

// snip
```